# Appending Items to a SimpleFocusListWalker in Urwid

Tags: python, python-2.7, urwid

Rather than do this as in the [urwid example](http://urwid.org/tutorial/index.html#horizontal-menu):

```
   simple_walker = urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker([
        urwid.AttrMap(urwid.Text([u'\n  ',caption]), 'heading'),
        urwid.AttrMap(line, 'line'),
        urwid.Divider()] + choices + [urwid.Divider()])
   self.listbox=urwid.ListBox(simple_walker)
```

I'd like to do this:

```
    simple_walker = urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker([])
    simple_walker.append(urwid.AttrMap(urwid.Text([u'\n  ',caption]), 'heading'))
    simple_walker.append(urwid.AttrMap(line, 'line'))
    simple_walker.append(urwid.Divider())
    simple_walker.append(choices)
    simple_walker.append(urwid.Divider())
    self.listbox=urwid.ListBox(simple_walker)
```

However, when I do this I get a long exception dump ending in:

```
  File ".../listbox.py", line 717, in _set_focus_complete
(maxcol,maxrow), focus)
   File ".../listbox.py", line 687, in _set_focus_first_selectable
(maxcol, maxrow), focus=focus)
   File ".../listbox.py", line 419, in calculate_visible
n_rows = next.rows( (maxcol,) )
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rows'

What is the correct way to append items to a SimpleFocusListWalker.

I'm trying to build a menu from the top down without specifying the whole thing in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The problem above was that "choices" is a list.  Needs to be the following:

```
for ii in choices:
    simple_walker.append(ii)
```

Comment: You could also do `simple_walker.extend(choices)`

Comment: D'oh!  Yes.    That would be more elegant.